# IntelliJ IDEA shortcut keymap for matching brace

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

What is the keymap for navigating to the matching brace in IntelliJ IDEA?

```
public void blah() {|
   ...

}
```

If `|` is my cursor, I would like to jump to the closing brace with this keymap.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5240995/20770

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "bracket" to "brace" because this is what your example shows - and the accepted answer doesn't work for brackets

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I've only verified this with IntelliJ 9 but:

On Windows:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> will move to the close
  bracket.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> will move to the open bracket.

On Mac:

- Use  <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Try cmd+alt+}. Worked for me on OSX 10.5+ Keymap

Comment: Brackets (`[` and `]`) also work. This generally is called jumping to the start / end of a block.

Comment: Do someone maybe know why those hotkeys don't work on alternative versions of conditions, like for example `if():` and `endif`?

Comment: I'm using Intelli 2017.1.4 and am able to do it with `shift` + `cmd` + `M`

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> you can by default use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> respectively. I haven't even tried to remember that yet. ;)

Also in Settings -> (IDE Settings ->) Keymap -> Editor Actions there's an entry called "Move Caret to Matched Brace" that doesn't have a default key mapping. I mapped it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> because the key combination was unmapped and the keys are close to each other on a german keyboard.

This applies to IDEA 12.

Comment: It's just impossible to use the original shortcut with a french Azerty keyboard !!! So I had to use the keymap settings.

Answer (score 10):

Its ^M (control + M) on my Mac using IDEA v15 and keeping the default keymap for MacOSX 10.5+

If you are not sure go to prefs and search for "Move Caret to Matching Brace". That's the name of the command and you can set your own shortcut!

Comment: Same.  It is ^M (ctrl-M) on a Mac for IntelliJ 2019.  See ``IntelliJ > Preferences... > Keymap > Editor Actions > Move Caret to Matching Brace`` to be sure

Answer (score 8):

On some keyboards, including Swedish ones, it's not practical to use Ctrl-} or Ctrl-{.  The best approach I've found under those circumstances is to double-click the bracket in view, which highlights everything between the brackets, then use left-arrow or right-arrow to move to the appropriate end of the highlighted region.

Comment: For a keyboard-only version: use `CTRL-W` to expand the selection within a bracket, use repeatedly if needed to select further out, then use the arrows like you say.

Comment: @Stoffe this is really useful because it works for _brackets_ and not only _braces_

Comment: @Stoffe - you mean `CTRL-w CTRL-w`, with a small w, don't you? I couldn't get to anything using capital W, at least not in WebStorm. Thank you for putting me on the right track, anyway :-)

Comment: @Muzietto yeah, I'd written CTRL-SHIFT-W or similar otherwise, it's supposed to be the buttons. But I see how that could be unclear.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> only moves the cursor to the closes corresponding brace that embraces ( with its counterpart) the place where you called the shortcut.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> moves the cursor to the same brace as the first mentioned shortcut and highlights all the area between start point and the result brace.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> moves the cursor to the opposite or nearest embracing brace or bracket of any sort ( ), { }, < >, [ ].

The last one can be changed in the settings.

Comment: Thanks this should be the top answer (ctrl + shift + m)

Answer (score 3):

@dhable is also right but you can also do this mouse

> place the cursor with braces and double click so this will select or
>    highlight the code bw braces

[image]

Comment: That's a nice feature