# Intellij IDEA find matching markup tag

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a shortcut or where I can click to find the matching tag of a markup tag and bring the focus/cursor there?

For example, 
`<p><span></span><div></div></p>`

If my cursor is on the closing `</p>` tag, I would like to IDEA to bring me to the opening `</p>` tag.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> goes to the **opening** tag
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> goes to the **closing** tag

The action is called `Move caret to code block end/start` and hotkey can be changed in `Settings | Keymap`.

On **IntelliJ 2017 for Mac** the shortcuts are:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> goes to the **opening** tag
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> goes to the **closing** tag

Comment: I'm working with Freemarker files (.ftl) and it doesn't work for it. Is there a way to make it work for Freemarker files?

Comment: What language is set for these files in Settings | Template Data Languages?

Comment: Nothing was set. I tried setting it to HTML and then tried Ctrl+[  and it still didn't work

Comment: Please file an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with a small sample project attached.

Comment: @GarfieldKlon, change the shortcuts in `Settings` | `Keymap`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder any idea why it fails to work for `.html.erb` files? Works fine in pure HTML or CSS files but I'm having trouble using it in my Rails views.

Comment: It works fine in IntelliJ 13 with a Swiss keyboard, if you remap the key to CTRL + "è/ü" and "umlaut". Because the opening/closing brakets are on these keys, but accessible with the "Alt Gr" modifier.

Answer (score 6):

On IntelliJ 2016 for Mac this command seems to be:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> goes to the matching tag / brace

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac, I use `Move caret to matching brace`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.