# IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcut for matching bracket

Tags: intellij-idea

If `|` is my cursor position

```
 List<String> words = Arrays.asList(|"all cats are grey".split(" "));
```

Then I would like a shortcut to jump to the closing bracket

```
 List<String> words = Arrays.asList("all cats are grey".split(" ")|);
```

Note, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351081/intellij-idea-shortcut-keymap-for-matching-brace) the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> work for jumping between braces `{ }` but not for brackets `( )`

Note 2: with standard IntelliJ keymap

Answer (score 5):

### **Ctrl + Shift + M**

(on Windows)

Now, there is actually an action called **Move Caret to Matching Brace**, that does like in the question.

Comment: `^M` is the shortcut for the same command on Mac

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there isn't a specific action to move cursor to the matching bracket.

This does it in 2 keystrokes and is the best I've found (Windows): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which selects the block up to the matching bracket, then <kbd>▶</kbd>

That's almost as quick, and better than switching to the mouse.

Comment: Useful tip, just one note: when the method call has multiple arguments (`foo("a", "b")`), you will have to press CTRL+W twice to get to the closing bracket.

Comment: `Ctrl+w` bad to get used to it lest yo uwant to quickly close your browser :)

Comment: @akostadinov yeah, I was on Windows back then, but on Mac now, and had to relearn a few things :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there exists a shortcut for round parenthesis.
I am working with IntelliJ for years, never found one.

`Ctrl` +`Key` depends on your Keymap.
You can change it in Settings -> Keymap -> [Keymaps:].
I haven't found round parenthesis, but I could have overlooked it.

***Edit***:
A possible solution would be, to install the Plugin IdeaVim and use `Shift` + `%`

http://vim.rtorr.com/